# What is the name of process of combining this two sentences?

Tags: grammar

I read the following sentence from a book.

> Since then, however, records have been introduced, offering a concise typed approach that we will describe in the following section.

I understand the meaning of this sentence. I think it can also be rewritten as follows.

> 1. Since then, however, records have been introduced.
> 2. They offer a concise typed approach that we will describe in the following section.

or

> Since then, however, records, that offer a concise typed approach that we will describe in the following section, have been introduced.

I am wondering what kind of grammar is used by the book author.

- Why does ", offering ..." comes after `... been introduced`?
- Why does "offer" become "offering"?
- What kind of grammar is it? What is the name of this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can split the original example into the 2 sentences you have shown.

The following rewording

> *Since then, however, records, **that** offer a concise typed approach that we will describe in the following section, have been introduced.

has errors.  The first relativiser **that** should not have a comma preceding it.

> Since then, however, records **that** offer a concise typed approach that we will describe in the following section have been introduced.

If you want to express the relative clause as a non-defining one, you should use **which**.  Commas are then allowed.

> Since then, however, records, **which** offer a concise typed approach that we will describe in the following section, have been introduced.

This construction can also be seen to have the second sentence of the two-sentence version inserted into the first in the form of a relative clause. In this construction, the clause **records have been introduced** has its subject and verbs separated by a long relative clause.  We can bring them together by [extraposition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition).

> Extraposition is a mechanism of syntax that alters word order in such a manner that a relatively "heavy" constituent appears to the right of its canonical position.

> Since then, however, **records have been introduced**, **which offer** a concise typed approach that we will describe in the following section.

**which offer** can be **reduced to a gerund-participle**:

> Since then, however, records have been introduced, **offering** a concise typed approach that we will describe in the following section.

The steps taken to change the sentence from each construction to its next version are described above.

Comment: +1, this is an excellent answer!